# How to serialize an object containing an Image?

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

How i can sent object with `Image`? I am getting this error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image
```

I can sent normal object, e. String, or whatever other objects.

```
     public void sentObject(Card GraczK) throws IOException 
     {

            outt.writeObject(GraczK);
            outt.flush();
            System.out.print(GraczK);

      }
```

CARD type

```
public class Card implements Serializable {
private int Value, Colour;

private Image img;

public Card(int i, int j) {
    Colour = i;
    Value = j;
    img = new Image(null, MainWarSever.class.getResourceAsStream("/Karty/k" + Value + " (" + Colour + ").png"));
}

public int getValue() {
    return Value;
}

public int getColour() {
    return Colour;
}

public Image getImg() {
    return img;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How i can sent object with an `Image`?

You can't serialize an `Image`.  It is typically "hooked into" the sender's graphics environment in ways that serialization is not able to deal with.

What you need to do is to mark the `img` field as `transient`.  The net effect will be that the receiver sees `null` as the value.  If you need to, you can then (re-)populate the field by loading an equivalent `Image` from a JAR or WAR (or somewhere else) on the receiving end.  (This implies that it would be a good idea to include a "name" for the card's image to facilitate the image load.)

You could use custom `readObject` / `writeObject` methods to hide this, but they probably need to be coded to do the same as the above ... under the hood.

You could also (I guess) turn the `Image` pixels into a byte array, transmit that, and reconstruct the pixels into an `Image` at the other end.  However that is going to bloat the "message" you are sending, and there may be further problems.  So I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot serialize an Image, just mark that field transient.
If still want to serialize it, then alternative is add another field to your class

```
private String imgBase64String; // Image to Base64 String.
```

convert your image into Base64 String. It can be serialize/deserialize. And Base64 String can convert back to Image.